# select id from table where it equals to row name

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to store the id of a username which I got from `$_SESSION` to a variable but I can't get the SQL statement to work. The usernames are stored in a database called users and have an ID as primary key. Can someone tell me how I can correct this? Thanks

```
$name = $_SESSION['username']; //get username of user currently logged in

$rid = $db->exec("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$name'");
```

Comment: Either there are no id's matching the tested username or the exec function isn't doing it's job properly.

Comment: @AndrewLarsen It is the latter and I think the query is flawed

Comment: Am I right to assume this is PDO? @thenoob If thats the case, set PDO to throw exceptions, use a try/catch and get the actual error thrown back at you. Without knowing that, its just a wild guess. Is the session started? Does that variable hold a value at all? Is it the right value?

Comment: can you print or display the session username to confirm if the session is not empty

Comment: @Qirel the session is started and the variable does not hold a value. When I used var_dump I got false

Comment: Enable error-reporting, by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the top of your file, directly after `<?php` - that will likely provide more information. How do you know for sure the session is started?

Comment: @maSTArHiAn yes I have another statement to just echo the username from session and it displays the username. Its the second line and I think the query isn't right but do not know how to solve it

Comment: Add var_dump($rid); to the end and see what kind of data you receive from the function call. And it would help alot if you could show us the code for the function exec.

Comment: and you reckon your connection is working? can you replace $name with a static value and see if you get a result back from the db.

Comment: @Qirel I get no no errors. Basically I am trying to add the id of the username as a FK in another but I need to get the ID first

Comment: @AndrewLarsen I get a boolean false. Does that mean it's empty?

Comment: It means it returns false. If you add the code from the function "exec" we can see if we figure it out.

Comment: @AndrewLarsen Its this one http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php

Comment: How can we be certain he doesn't have his own class with his own function? However we need to see the code in order to solve this.

Comment: @thenoob If you look at my two comments above, combine those and you will get error-reporting from PHP and PDO. This will allow you to figure out exactly what went wrong. Without the errors, we can't do much but guess.

Comment: @maSTArHiAn I do not get a return back when it is of a static value

Comment: simply shows your db connection does not work

Comment: @AndrewLarsen By all means, but it seems highly unlikely that this is an extension of the PDO class... There's little to extend that particular method with anyway.

Comment: @Qirel what would I catch for? Can you write the code I'm not familiar with handling erros

Comment: Well if it is PDO you can try to add var_dump($db->errorInfo()); at the bottom and see what you get.

Comment: @thenoob  Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php - basically wrap your connection and the `exec()` method in a `try` block, with `catch (PDOException $e) { print_r($e); }` after it. And of course PHP error reporting, check your logs etc. You need to set PDO to throw exceptions though.

Comment: @maSTArHiAn it does work, it adds other variables in but struggling with the username one

Comment: @AndrewLarsen when I use  var_dump($db->errorInfo());, I get array (size=3)
  0 => string '00000' (length=5)
  1 => null
  2 => null

Comment: @Qirel I am not getting any errors using the try catch

Comment: @thenoob Then what exactly is the value of `$name`? `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: when I do var_dump I get a 0 not false because i mistyped the code

Comment: @Qirel its the username i created to log in, zxcv123. var_dump($name) gives me the username as a string so it has to be the second line of code thats gone wrong

Comment: @AndrewLarsen var_dump of $rid gives 0 not false sorry

Comment: Can't believe we missed this and went down a bunch of other rabbit-holes, but `exec()` doesn't work for `SELECT` queries. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP documentation on `PDO::exec()`:

> PDO::exec() does not return results from a SELECT statement. For a SELECT statement that you only need to issue once during your program, consider issuing PDO::query(). For a statement that you need to issue multiple times, prepare a PDOStatement object with PDO::prepare() and issue the statement with PDOStatement::execute().

This means that you cannot use `exec()` on a SELECT query - instead, you must use `query()` or `prepare()`. For any queries using variables or user-input, use `prepare()` and placeholders in the query for variables, like below, to protect your database against *SQL-injection*.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :name");
$stmt->execute(["name" => $name]);
if ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // $row holds the id
} else {
    // No rows were returned at all! No matches for $name
}
```

Now `$row` holds the id(s) if the query returned any result at all. Depending on your fetch-type, it might be `$row['id']`, `$row[0]`, `$row->id` or a combination of these.

If you expect more than one result, you need to loop `while ($row = $stmt->fetch())`, or use `$stmt->fetchAll();`

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thank you its fixed it but when I try to insert $row into db, I get an error of array to string conversion

Comment: That's because you need to use `$row['id']` or `$row[0]`, not `$row` (which is an array!), this depends on your fetch-type - read the last two paragraphs in the answer, just above the two links.